# Posting an update to a group on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wish to post an update on a group using Facebook Graph API

I am using the `GET` http method to achieve this, after reading the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/group/feed) this is what I have come up with :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/group_id/feed?message=test&access_token=access_token
```

**Current Output:**

> When I use to URL, I and parse it, I just get a JSON data with the whole feed of the group.

**Expected Output:**

> I expect the message "test" to be posted onto the group.

How do I go about this?

Here is all the permissions my access token is granted with:

[image]

***NOTE:***

I am using v2.9 of the Graph API and I am the admin of the group also, the group is public

Comment: are you doing an http POST or GET?

Comment: I am using GET() @atimothee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use http POST not GET to publish a new post to the group feed, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/group/feed).

```
POST /v2.9/{group-id}/feed HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com

message=This+is+a+test+message
```

Also, make sure your access token has the following permissions `publish_actions` and `user_managed_groups`.

Comment: Oops, forgot the fact I had to use POST. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Could you help me a out further? I tried `$.post("https://graph.facebook.com/"+idList[ind]+"/feed?message=test&access_token=token",function(messag){alert("success");});` but for some reason it's not running.

Comment: what error is returned? are you sure you have the `publish_actions` and `user_managed_groups`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it figured!